# Laravel iterate over all models

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5.6

Is there a way to iterate over all models?

I have a strucure `app/Models/{?ModelDir}/{Model}`. I just need to check if controller for each model if it uses a trait.

Iterating through the models looks a nice solution for me but I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Should be the same process as iterating any directory, add reflection if you need to verify a class extends Model.

Comment: You could use Reflection:http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.gettraits.php

Comment: Thanks for help. Iterating through dirs was actually what I needed